# SQL Trigger: Copy A Row From One Table When Column Value Changes?

Tags: sql, database-trigger

```
   Create Trigger trig_UserLogins_ForUpdate On [dbo].[UserLogins]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
Begin
Set nocount on
If (Select Verified From INSERTED) = 1
Begin
Select FirstName, Lastname, CDName,
WID, Email, PhoneNum, Verified
From Inserted i

Insert Into [dbo].[Worker_DB] FirstName, LastName, DisplayName, WID, Email, PhoneNumber, Verified
VALUES (i.First, i.Last, i.Display, i.WID,i.Email, i.phone,i.Verified)
End
End
```

some guidance on how to have this executed when the Verified column is updated to "true",  the row has to transfer to another database called Workers_DB.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Please tell us which database technology you are using, and post some DDL. I have no idea what you mean by column 1 2 3 4 5 6 7. Do you want to copy the same value from the first table into all 7 columns in the second table?

Comment: Using SQLServer.    Yes you are correct all data gets copied.

Answer (score 0):

You would write an `insert` (and perhaps an `update`) trigger on  `datebase1.table1`.

That trigger would have conditional logic that looked at the values going into the table.

If the conditions are met, then it would do the appropriate actions on the table in the second database.